# how to cast Collection to Entity Object in jsf?

Tags: jsf-2

I have taken **`Collection<Edition> selectedEditions;`** .When I iterate like this :

```
    Collection<Edition> edlist=(java.util.Collection)selectedEditions;         
for(Edition ed:edlist){ // error at this line
            EditionID=ed.getEditionID();
            NewspaperID=ed.getNewspaper().getNewspaperID();
            StateID=ed.getCity().getState().getStateID();
            System.out.print("nid..........."+NewspaperID);
            System.out.print("sid..........."+StateID);
        }
```

Then it gives error like:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to entity.Edition
my getter setter:

```
public Collection<Edition> getSelectedEditions() {
                return selectedEditions;
}
public void setSelectedEditions(Collection<Edition> selectedEditions) {
        this.selectedEditions = selectedEditions;
    }
```

and

```
                              </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                            <h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{adcreateBean.selectedEditions}"  var="it" styleClass="nostyle" width="100%">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="You have selected :" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:column>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{it}" />
                                     </h:column>
                                   </h:dataTable>
```

So,How can I cast to entity.Edition? 
As told in answer of this question([[How can I get multiselected checkbox value in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065427/how-can-i-get-multiselected-checkbox-value-in-jsf][1])), how can I convert?

[How can I get multiselected checkbox value in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065427/how-can-i-get-multiselected-checkbox-value-in-jsf)

Answer (score 2):

As commented/answered in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066083/how-to-get-name-of-the-selected-checkbox-value-from-id), you just need to create a custom `Converter` which converts between `String` and `Edition`. You just have to create a class which implements [`javax.faces.convert.Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) and then implement the methods accordingly.

```
@FacesConverter("editionConverter")
public class EditionConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        // Write code yourself which converts from Edition object to its unique 
        // String representation. This string will then be used in HTML and HTTP.
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        // Write code yourself which converts from unique String representation
        // back to Edition object. This object will then be used in JSF model.
    }

}
```

Usually, the technical ID is been used as unique `String` representation. Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
@FacesConverter("editionConverter")
public class EditionConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        Long id = (object instanceof Edition) ? ((Edition) object).getId() : null;
        return (id != null) ? String.valueOf(id) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        Long id = (submittedValue != null) ? Long.valueOf(submittedValue) : null;
        return (id != null) ? someEditionService.find(id) : null;
    }

}
```

Finally use it on the `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... converter="editionConverter">
```

Please note that this is **absolutely not** the same as casting. `Edition` isn't a superclass or subclass of `String` at all. To understand what exactly casting is, please read [Oracle's own basic Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).